# What is the expected behavoir when StreamBridge.send method returns false?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I notice a lot of usage of the StreamBridge.send method in Spring Cloud Stream apps but none of them check its return value.

What is the expected behavior when the send method returns false? Should we do the retry if it returns false?

@OlegZhurakousky

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It means that the `channel.send()` returned false. As for `Should we do the retry`, i don't know as I don't know your requirements.

Also, I would be interested why are you using `StreamBridge`? Indeed it is a component of s-c-stream, but 90% of what it does could be done in a more idiomatic way without it. In fact it was designed for one specific purpose, hence my interest.

Comment: The use case is to send a message received from a hosted REST service to a Kafka topic using Kafka producer API: Message ---> POST to REST service ---> Send to Kafka topic.

Comment: Good, just wanted to know. That is the correct use case for using SB.